# Alternative proof that maximal abelian normal subgroups of a nilpotent group are self-centralizing

Tags: group-theory, alternative-proof, normal-subgroups, nilpotent-groups

I was writing lecture notes on nilpotent groups, and wanted to show the following well-known basic result.

**Theorem**: Let $G$ be a nilpotent group and let $A$ be an abelian normal subgroup of $G$, maximal amongst such subgroups. Then $A=C_G(A)$.

The standard proof of this is easy: certainly $C=C_G(A)$ contains $A$, so if this is proper then consider $C/A$. As this is a non-trivial normal subgroup of $G/A$ it intersects the centre non-trivially, so let $x\neq 1$ be in this intersection. The subgroup $\langle A,x\rangle$ is abelian, since $A$ commutes with $x$, and normal since $\langle A,x\rangle/A$ is central, hence normal in $G/A$. Since $A$ is maximal, this yields a contradiction.

Now, the problem is that when I was writing this result, I had not yet proved that normal subgroups intersect the centre non-trivially, so I tried to come up with a proof that did not use that. In the end I gave up and rearranged the results so the other one came first. But is there a proof that doesn't essentially prove the normal subgroups result along the way? (Note that I am not assuming that $G$ is finite, or even finitely generated.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can reason like this.

Let $A$ be a maximal normal abelian subgroup of nilpotent group $G$ and $C=C_G(A)$.
Note at once that $C$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.
Let
$$
1=Z_0\leq Z_1\leq\ldots\leq Z_s=G
$$
be the upper central series of $G$.

Prove by induction that $C\cap Z_i\leq A$ for all $i$.
It is clear that $C\cap Z_0\leq A$. Let $C\cap Z_i\leq A$
and let $h\in C\cap Z_{i+1}$.

For any $g\in G$ we have $[g,h]\in Z_i\cap C\leq A$.
Hence, the group $\langle A,h\rangle$ is a normal Abelian subgroup of $G$. Then $h\in A$.

Finally we obtain that $C\cap G=C\cap Z_s\leq A$, hence $C=A$.

Comment: That certainly works. I'm worried that if I set $A=1$ and $C$ to be an arbitrary normal subgroup of $G$, you have just proved that if $Z(G)\cap N=1$ then $G\cap N=1$, i.e., $N=1$. I was trying to decide whether the two results are, in fact, equivalent.

Comment: At least these two results can be proven using the same scheme.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven There are non-nilpotent groups where one property holds but other doesn't.  For example: (1) $SL(2,q)$ for $q > 2$ odd every normal subgroup has nontrivial intersection with the center. But the center is maximal abelian normal, and not self-centralizing. (2) In $G = S_3$ the unique maximal abelian normal subgroup is self-centralizing. But it has trivial intersection with the center. I guess there should also be groups where both properties hold, but the group is not nilpotent.

Comment: @spin The self-centralizing maximal normal abelian subgroups thing also holds for any supersoluble group, so there's a good chance, yes.

Comment: @spin How about a $p$-constrained group of the form $p^n\cdot X$ where $X$ is a simple group and the $p^n$ forms a $\mathbb F_pX$-module with a unique trivial submodule? Every normal subgroup contains that subgroup of order $p$, which is central, and the whole $p^n$ the unique maximal abelian normal subgroup, and is self-centralizing. (And by equivalent I simply meant one can easily prove one from the other in a nilpotent group, I didn't mean that one held iff the other did. It was a poor choice of words.)